# Can't add South to Django 1.6.2 Project

Tags: django, django-south

I've got an existing Django project that I'm trying to add South to.  I'm fine with losing ally my data (in fact, I've already dropped/created the database several times).

The problem is that I do the following:

(in `psql`)

1. `drop database myproject`
2. `create database myproject`

(at the command line)

1. `python manage.py syncdb --migrate`
2. `python manage.py schemamigration myproject.myapp --initial`
3. `python manage.py migrate myproject.myapp`

Everything works great until I get to that last command; when I run it I get:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "myapp_somemodel" already exists

(where "somemodel" is a model in myapp).

I've tried searching SO, but all the posts I found suggested the set of commands above.  Can anyone please help me get South added to this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `migrate` with `--fake` option for your initial migration:

```
$ python manage.py migrate myproject.myapp 0001 --fake
```

Also see [Converting An App](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app) chapter from `South` docs.